# What is the best way to bind dynamics values in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am using a Dictionary<string,string> to store some options, the key is the name of the option and as you guess the value is the value of the correspendent option.

in my razor file i have this bit of code :

```cs
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> option in templates.templatesList[SelectionValue])
{
    <tr>
        <td>@option.Key</td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
}
```

And what i'm searching to do is to store the value of the text input into the right value in my Dictionary, sadly we can not use @bind = @option.Value.

Comment: Why can't you use  @bind = option.Value

Comment: It seems that the value is read only type, you can't modify it, at least not in the razor file

Comment: Try to bind to templates.templatesList[SelectionValue][option.Key]

Comment: @Vi100 Keys and Values are readonly, so it's hard to outmaneuver this outside the object class, i pruposed a temporary solution that works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution for the next googlers:

An alternative way to bind a value is to use @onchange option like described here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

So, i changed the code as follow :

in the razor file :

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> option in templates.templatesList[SelectionValue])
{

    <tr>
        <td><label>@option.Key</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => changeOption(__e,option.Key))" /></td>
    </tr>

}

public void changeOption(ChangeEventArgs __e, string key)
{
    templates.changeValue(SelectionValue, key, __e.Value.ToString());
}
```

And in My object class (Template)

```
public void changeValue(string template, string option, string value)
    {
        this.templatesList[template][option] = value;
    }
```

I don't know if it's the cleanest thing to do it this way or not, but it does the job perfectly.

Comment: And how do you reset values ?